# Error creating repository bean with Spring

Tags: scala, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I set up Neo4j-Kernel 1.9M04 and Spring-Data-Neo4j 2.1.0 RELEASE.

More precisely, here my dependencies (from my SBT file):

```
    "org.springframework" % "spring-aop" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-aspects" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-beans" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-commons-core" % "1.4.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-expression" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-jdbc" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-orm" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-test" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework" % "spring-tx" % "3.2.0.RELEASE",
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j" % "2.1.0.RELEASE" excludeAll(
      ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jdmk"),
      ExclusionRule(organization = "com.sun.jmx"),
      ExclusionRule(organization = "javax.jms")
      ),
    "org.neo4j" % "neo4j" % "1.9.M04",
    "org.neo4j" % "neo4j-kernel" % "1.9.M04" % "test" classifier "tests" classifier "",
    "asm" % "asm-all" % "3.1",
    "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.13" % "test" withSources(),
    "org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j-rest" % "2.1.0.RELEASE"
```

At runtime, trying to autowire a neo4j repository, I've got this stack:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/LockReleaser
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/LockReleaser
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1808) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:384) ~[spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:322) ~[spring-orm-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:844) ~[spring-beans-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.LockReleaser
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) ~[na:1.7.0_07]
```

I noticed that the class `org/neo4j/kernel/impl/core/LockReleaser`has disappeared from Neo4J 1.9M0X.

It seems that the error provides from `"org.springframework.data" % "spring-data-neo4j-rest" % "2.1.0.RELEASE"`

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like spring-orm was build against different version of neo4j than you're trying to use at runtime (they are incompatible).

Possible solutions:

- Use older version of neo4j.
- Build spring-orm yourself against your current version of neo4j. Likely you will have to migrate spring-orm yourself.

Comment: I can't use an older version of Neo4j since scala 2.10 isn't compatible with neo4j's version older than 1.9M04 ..

Comment: It seems that Spring-Data-Neo4j 3.2.0.RELEASE doesn't fully support Neo4j 1.9.X version. Best solution to keep Scala 2.10 as main language is to not use Spring Data and go back to traditional Neo4j APIs.